# How to add data-autocomplete HTML attribute to TextBoxFor HTML helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete, razor

autocomplete text box for getting city autocomplete textbox.

My code look like this,

```
<input id="location" type="text" name="q" 
data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("locationSearch", "Home", 
                       new { text = "location" })"/>
```

Now i want to convert this to razor syntex. I tried this but not working.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Location, 
   new { data-autocomplete = Url.Action("locationSearch", "Home")})
```

How can i solve this??

Answer (score 7):

data-autocomplete is an HTML attribute. First of all you can't use dashes when specifying attributes in MVC, therefore you need to replace your data-autocomplete with data_autocomplete. MVC is "smart enough" and final result will read data-autocomplete.

To add an HTML attribute to your text input you need to use the following HTML helper:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Location, new { data_autocomplete = Url.Action("locationSearch", "Home") })
```

Answer (score 1):

u can just use this

in your view

```
<select id="location" name="location"></select>

           <input type="submit" value="Send">
```

that is actually dropdownlist, not textbox, they edit the layout via css

Answer (score 0):

You should use undescore symbol in HtmlAttributes argument:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Location, new { data_autocomplete = Url.Action("locationSearch", "Home")})
```